# MySQL/PHP Importing CSV Files - Auto Increment Gap

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am importing CSV files into a MySQL Database using a foreach loop to run through every file in a directory.

I have written a SQL Query to copy in just the relevant information, after all columns have been added to a temporary table, named with an id number for each file.

For some reason that I cannot figure out, when testing with two files (Each with around 325 rows) the ID's in the final table make a huge jump between the first file and the second. E.g. File 1 Id's go from 1 - 325 then File 2 Id's start at 512 instead of 326.

[image]

Here is what I am using to copy the information:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO wowcher.hermes (Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, Address_Line_3, Address_Line_4,
    Postcode, First_Name, Reference, Delivery_Safe_Place, Wowcher_Code, Deal_ID)
    SELECT Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2, City, County, Postcode, Customer_Name, Product_Name, Product_Options, Wowcher_Code, Deal_ID
    FROM `$dealId` WHERE Custom_Field = 'Yes' AND Product_Name NOT LIKE '%160x230%' AND Postcode NOT LIKE 'JE%' AND Postcode NOT LIKE 'GY%' $notIre");
}
```

I actually have three files to be imported, however only two of them contain information to go into this table, so perhaps the third file without rows to copy, is causing a problem with the loop and forcing the auto increment numbers up?

I need the auto incrementing Id's to be unbroken, so that I can use a for loop to edit the information when the count of the loop is equal to certain Id's.

Comment: "I need the auto incrementing Id's to be unbroken, so that I can use a for loop to edit the information when the count of the loop is equal to certain Id's." Do you? As you've discovered, that's not very reliable. What about another identifier - I notice a "Deal ID" in there. Is that not the unique identifer here? I doubt your third file is interfering, if it doesn't insert any rows. Maybe something else is deleting them. Or have you deleted and re-tried? It won't re-use IDs again, even if they've since been deleted.

Comment: I know its not very reliable, but unfortunately I cannot find any way of doing what I want to achieve with the for loop easily. So I have had to come up with a fairly convoluted work around. Essentially I am doing a find and replace on every Product_Name I need them to be shorter than 32 characters, I couldn't find a way with a single SQL query to do exactly what I want. Deal ID is the name of the file, so any number of rows have the same Deal ID. I need "SELECT * WHERE ID = $count", this wont work if the Id's are broken up

Comment: Go to operations of table an set the AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: if you want to shorten the product name to 32 characters, you can do it when you insert the rows. In that sample you gave in the question, use `SELECT .... LEFT(Product_name, 32)...`

Comment: I need to be able to shorten it whilst also keeping certain key words, so unfortunately it's not as simple as that. Thanks though

Comment: ok. so, when you loop through update them, instead of doing `SELECT * WHERE ID = $count`, why not just select _all_ the rows to start with, and then loop through each one? That way you get all the rows, but you don't need to care what the ID is. Then you can update that single row based on its ID, which you can read when the loop reaches it. Also that way you have one SELECT statement instead of hundreds.

Comment: I have thought of that but don't really understand how I could loop through all the rows without using information stored in the table like an ID. Could you explain in more detail? This would be very helpful

Comment: I assume you're using PHP to do this? You just select all the rows. You get them back into PHP as an array. Then you loop through the array in the normal way (using for, while, whatever). Every time you loop, you are dealing with a different row. You can access the values of all the fields you selected (including the ID). Change the product name field how you need to, then run an UPDATE statement against the database row with that ID. You can find plenty of examples of this online, just get the one relevant to your DB engine (mysqli, PDO or whatever).